# Is Teamcenter Visualization Professional/Mockup/Normal etc customizable?

Tags: teamcenter

The Teamcenter rich client (RAC) is customizable, since it is an application based on Eclipse. However, Teamcenter Visualization tools seem to be an individual component in the Teamcenter suite.

**Is it possible to customize this software?** My goal is to develop a mobile app to control the Vis View/Mockup application remotely. In the first step, it is not necessary to visualize the 3D image. Only finger gesture is enough. In the second step, it would be nice to synchronize the 3D image in the desktop and the mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that  teamcenter visualization software already support as mobile app, i don't think so you will able to do any customization with Visualization....but still you have chance to go through the installation directory and find out exiting setup file if you can catch up some thing.

Answer (score 1):

Teamcenter Visualization has a mobile app already. But to answer your first part of the question, TCVis is built with COM components. Though i am not sure whether any documentation is available or not from vendor, atleast it is possible to invoke tcvis app by starting with FrameBroker and ObjectBroker dlls. Just add reference to those dlls, and you will find functions to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the COM API is in the installation folder C:\Program Files\Siemens\Teamcenter11.1\Visualization\Examples\Automation\Documentation\Start.html

Answer (score -1):

You can customize Teamcenter Visualization but you should have license on SDK